# Apache Beam Go SDK: how to convert PCollection<string> to PCollection<KV<string, string>>?

Tags: go, type-conversion, apache-beam, key-value

I'm using the Apache Beam Go SDK and having a hard time getting a **PCollection** in the correct format for grouping/combining by key.

I have multiple records per key in a PCollection of strings that look like this:

```
Bob, cat
Bob, dog
Carla, cat
Carla, bunny
Doug, horse
```

I want to use **GroupByKey** and **CombinePerKey** so I can aggregate each person's pets like this:

```
Bob, [cat, dog]
Carla, [cat, bunny]
Doug, [horse]
```

**How do I convert a PCollection<string> to PCollection<KV<string, string>>?**

They mention something similar [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/), but the code to aggregate the string values is not included.

I can use a ParDo to get the string key and string value as shown below, but I can't figure out how to convert to the KV<string, string> or CoGBK<string, string> format required as input to GroupPerKey.

```
pcolOut := beam.ParDo(s, func(line string) (string, string) {
  cleanString := strings.TrimSpace(line)
  openingChar := ","
  iStart := strings.Index(cleanString, openingChar)
  key := cleanString[0:iStart]
  value := cleanString[iStart+1:]
        
// How to convert to PCollection<KV<string, string>> before returning?
  return key, value
}, pcolIn)

groupedKV := beam.GroupByKey(s, pcolOut)
```

It fails with the following error. Any suggestions?

```
panic:  inserting ParDo in scope root
        creating new DoFn in scope root
        binding fn main.main.func2
        binding params [{Value string} {Value string}] to input CoGBK<string,string>
values of CoGBK<string,string> cannot bind to {Value string}
```

Comment: I suspect the error is happening when you're using the groupedKV function.

The signature should be `ProcessElement(k string, iter func(*string) bool)`  (modulo, anything you're emitting out of it.)

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey shows an example with a cogbk, but it's the same for gbk, with only one iterator instead:
look at the `formatCoGBKResults` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To map to KVs, you can apply MapElements and use into() to set KV types and in the via() logic, create a new `KV.of(myKey, myValue)`, for example, to get a `KV<String,String>`, use something like this:

```
    PCollection<KV<String, String>> kvPairs = linkpages.apply(MapElements.into(
        TypeDescriptors.kvs(
            TypeDescriptors.strings(),
            TypeDescriptors.strings()))
        .via(
            linkpage -> KV.of(dataFile, linkpage)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mistake the next pardo iter type

test this code

```
pcolIn := beam.CreateList(s, []string{"Bob, cat",
    "Bob, dog",
    "Carla, cat",
    "Carla, bunny",
    "Doug, horse",
})

pcolOut := beam.ParDo(s, func(line string) (string, string) {
    cleanString := strings.TrimSpace(line)
    openingChar := ","
    iStart := strings.Index(cleanString, openingChar)
    key := cleanString[0:iStart]
    value := cleanString[iStart+1:]

    // How to convert to PCollection<KV<string, string>> before returning?
    return key, value
}, pcolIn)

groupedKV := beam.GroupByKey(s, pcolOut)

beam.ParDo0(s, func(key string, iter func(*string) bool) {
    vals := []string{}
    val := ""
    for iter(&val) {
        vals = append(vals, strings.TrimSpace(val))
    }
    fmt.Println(key, vals)
}, groupedKV)
```